# Plane projection of Geodesics (Inverse view)

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, geodesics

Maybe this question is so clear or maybe it is not exact. It is because of my very little knowledge of differential geometry. I am reading some material in this field and I got a question which seems has some meaning, but I am not sure.

Is it true that any simple curve $\gamma$ in the plane is geodesy of a finite volume Riemannian manifold $M$ in which its curvature is not zero? If this is true, is there any strategy to construct at least one manifold for that simple curve?

$\text{Added later by @Anton Petrunin suggestions:}$

**$\gamma$ is orthogonal projection to the plane and $M$ is a closed surface.**

I think the answer is positive, but I do not have any idea (except imagination) to prove it.

Actually, I did many searches and I did not find any answer in papers or books.

Comment: Related: [Is every closed curve in 3D a geodesic on a genus-0 surface?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/207365/6094).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Thanks for the link. It seems interesting and helpful!

Comment: You can take your simple curve (if it is embedded) to a circle by a diffeomorphism of the plane, which is the identity outside a compact set, and then bend your plane into a light bulb shape. Is that what you are looking for? The details of such an argument would be long, I suppose.

Comment: The formulation is very unclear. Did you want say that $\gamma$ is orthogonal projection to the plane and $M$ is a closed surface?

Comment: @Anton Petrunin: It seems that by your suggestion the problem will be more exact. I agree with the orthogonal projection and closed surface. Is there any positive answer in this case?

Comment: @Ben McKay: I can imagine what you say, but how can we prove that such bending is possible and the resulting projected curve on the light bulbe shape is a geodesic?

Comment: I believe that it is known (probably from Grayson's work on shrinking of curves) that, for any embedded closed smooth curve in the plane, there is a diffeomorphism of the plane taking that curve to a circle. From there you can be quite explicit, mapping the plane to, for example, a punctured sphere, so that the circle is mapped to a great circle, by projection from the north pole of the sphere (Ptolemaic projection).

Comment: Well, then you should change the question (others do not understand it still).

Answer (score 1):

So $\gamma$ is a simple plane curve; let us assume it is smooth and regular (otherwise the question has no sense).

Note that the curve $\gamma$ is a geodesic on the cylindrical surface $\mathbb{R}\times \gamma$.

This surface is has infinite area, but it is easy to fix, cut it by planes $z=\pm1$ and smooth the corners (it can be done explicitely in a tubular neighborhood of the corner).